# OSL error whend rendering/previewing in Beta 3.5

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, lighting, osl

Does anyone know why I get this error when trying to preview or render with Blender 3.5 Beta with OSL and light tree enabled?

> OSL group data size (2296) is greater than the maximum supported with OPTIX (2048)

And nothing gets rendered. How do I increase that data size pool and make it work?

Comment: Is it practical to include the OSL script in your post?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I'm just using stock 3.5 build from Blender website with "OSL" checkbox checked. Did not add any other scripts anywhere.

Comment: Sorry..  I thought, if you had OSL checked, it you would be to run [OSL Shaders](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/shader_nodes/osl.html) .  I'm not aware of another reason to do it, but am open to correction.

Comment: See maybe [#104304 - OPTIX OSL Group size error - blender - Blender Projects](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/104304#issuecomment-77123)

Answer (score -1):

Under *Render Settings* uncheck *Open Shading Language* setting.